# Logstash multiple pipeline -pipeline.yml chages

Tags: yaml, logstash, pipeline, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have written 2 pipeline in logstash pipeline.yml file having different pipeline id's as pipeline1 and pipeline 2.

- pipeline.id: my-pipeline-1
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/p1.config"
  pipeline.workers: 3
- pipeline.id: my-pipeline-2
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/p2.config"
  queue.type: persisted

what parameters i have to specify for configuration file of pipeline 1 and how to run that pipeline1's configuration file

I have used this:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html

But how to run configuration files with pipeline

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. Are you trying to run only pipeline 1 without running pipeline 2 ??

Please elaborate your question and add some config code etc.

Comment: I want multiple pipeline in logstash instead of 1 pipeline . By default logstash is having 1 pipeline . When we run configuration file in logstash then we put command logstash -f filename.config . In that -f used for ignoring pipeline. But if i want to use pipeline then how to use it

Comment: If you read the document correctly, if you don't pass any argument like `-f` or `-e` then the file `pipelines.yml` will be read and the pipelines will be started. Hope this will help [logstash: using multiple pipeline](https://web.leandrojmp.com/posts/en/2021/03/logstash-multiple-pipelines)

Comment: By running with -f option it is giving error